# Mysql: What is the difference between "slow_query_log" vs "log_slow_queries"

Tags: mysql, profiling, server-variables

If there is not any difference, why having two server parameters to achieve one behavior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`log_slow_queries` was deprecated in MySQL 5.1.29 by `slow-query-log`.
The [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) has more details.

Answer (score 8):

From mysql documentation:

> The --log-slow-queries option is deprecated and is removed (along with
>   the log_slow_queries system variable) in MySQL 5.6. Instead, use the
>   --slow_query_log option to enable the slow query log and the --slow_query_log_file=file_name option to set the slow query log file name.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries